# Привязка Command ContextMenu в HierarchicalDataTemplate TreeView

Tags: wpf, mvvm

```
<TreeView Focusable="False" Name="TreeViewCocos" Background="#87BECE" Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RectItems, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:StandartRectangelItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked}"/>

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Uid}" FontSize="16">
                                <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                    <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                                        <MenuItem Header="" Command={Binding ???} CommandParameter={Binding ???}/>
                                    </ContextMenu>
                                </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                            </TextBlock>

                            <Button Margin="5,0,0,0" Content="Copy" Width="27" Height="16" FontSize="10" Command="{Binding ElementName=TreeViewCocos, Path=DataContext.CopyNodeInfoCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Node}"/>
                            <Button Margin="5,0,0,0" Content="Get" FontSize="10" Height="16" Width="20" Command="{Binding ElementName=TreeViewCocos, Path=DataContext.ShowNodeInfoCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Node}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding ElementName=TreeViewCocos, Path=DataContext.IsExpandAllNodes, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </Style>
                </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            </TreeView>
```

Как через ContextMenu привязать Command, чтобы она отработала? Какой Context ей задать?
В примере с Button `Command="{Binding ElementName=TreeViewCocos, Path=DataContext.CopyNodeInfoCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Node}"` это работает, но в ContextMenu нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<TreeView.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenuTreeView">
       <MenuItem Header="Test" Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.ShowNodeInfoCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</TreeView.Resources>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Uid}" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" FontSize="16" ContextMenu="{DynamicResource ContextMenuTreeView}"/>
```